# Subclass constructor from two mainclasses

Tags: c++

I have the base class `Meateater` and two subclasses from `Meateater` called `Lion` and `Tiger`.

Now, I want to implement the class `Liger` that have `Lion` and `Tiger` as base class.

All other classes are implemented.
`Liger`constructor is now adjusted.

How do I have to call the constructor of `Liger` in the main file?

The class inheritance looks like this:

```
             Animals
           /         \
  Meateater           Grasseater
  /    |    \        /     |     \
Lion  Tiger  Puma   Cow   Pig   Sheep
  \    |  
    Liger
```

`ZooMain`:

```cpp
// #include <unistd.h>  // used for usleep
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cassert>
#include "consumables/Consumable.h"
#include "consumables/Grass.h"
#include "consumables/Meat.h"
#include "consumables/Water.h"
#include "employees/ZooDirector.h"
#include "employees/Zookeeper.h"
#include "employees/FarmZookeeper.h"
#include "employees/PredatorZookeeper.h"
#include "animals/Animal.h"
#include "animals/Meateater/mutation/Liger.h"
#include "template/Animals_vec.h"
#include "template/Random.h"
#include "template/Map_Animals.h"

/**
 * @brief   the main function of the ZooMain program
 * @return  0
 */
int main() {
  std::cout << "------- Launch zoo simulation  -------" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "------- create all animals  -------" << std::endl;
  // create animals
  std::vector<Animals::Cow*> cows;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    cows.push_back( new Animals::Cow(Template::random<unsigned int>(5, 10),
    Template::random<unsigned int>(0, 1)));
  }
  std::vector<Animals::Sheep*> sheeps;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    sheeps.push_back( new Animals::Sheep(Template::random<unsigned int>(4, 5),
    Template::random<unsigned int>(0, 1)));
  }
  std::vector<Animals::Lion*> lions;
    lions.push_back( new Animals::Lion(Template::random<unsigned int>(4, 5),
     1));
    lions.push_back( new Animals::Lion(Template::random<unsigned int>(4, 5),
     0));
  std::vector<Animals::Puma*> pumas;
    pumas.push_back( new Animals::Puma(Template::random<unsigned int>(4, 5),
     1));
    pumas.push_back( new Animals::Puma(Template::random<unsigned int>(4, 5),
     0));
  std::vector<Animals::Tiger*> tigers;
    tigers.push_back( new Animals::Tiger(Template::random<unsigned int>(4, 5),
    1));
    tigers.push_back( new Animals::Tiger(Template::random<unsigned int>(4, 5),
    0));

  // create all employees
  std::cout << "------- create all employees  -------" << std::endl;
  Employees::FarmZookeeper farmZookeeper(cows, sheeps);
  Employees::PredatorZookeeper predatorZookeeper(lions, pumas, tigers);
  Employees::ZooDirector& director = Employees::ZooDirector::getInstance();
  director.addZookeeper(&farmZookeeper);
  director.addZookeeper(&predatorZookeeper);
  for (int i = 0; i <= Template::random(5, 8); ++i) {
    std::cout << "------- start " << i << "th year -------" << std::endl;
    director.manage();
    for (auto& animal : Template::animals_vec(&farmZookeeper,
        &predatorZookeeper)) {
      //  Mating
      //  get_mating() is only true if the animal is not pregnant
      if (animal->get_mating() == true && animal->get_gender() == "male" &&
          animal->get_name() == "lion") {
        for (auto& potential_mate : Template::animals_vec(&farmZookeeper,
          &predatorZookeeper)) {
            if (potential_mate->get_name() == "tiger" &&
                potential_mate->get_gender() == "female" &&
                potential_mate->get_mating() == true) {
                potential_mate->pregnancy();
                //  push_out_animal is used for add the animal to the vec form the zookeeper
                //  This call is the problem
                predatorZookeeper.push_out_animal(new Animals::Liger(1,
                Template::random<unsigned int>(0, 1)));
            }
        }
      }
      if (animal->get_mating() == true && animal->get_gender() == "male") {
        for (auto& potential_mate : Template::animals_vec(&farmZookeeper,
          &predatorZookeeper)) {
            if (potential_mate->get_name() == animal->get_name() &&
                potential_mate->get_gender() == "female" &&
                potential_mate->get_mating() == true) {
                potential_mate->pregnancy();
                switch (Template::map_animals(animal->get_name())) {
                  case 1:
                      farmZookeeper.push_out_animal(new Animals::Cow(1,
                      Template::random<unsigned int>(0, 1)));
                      break;
                  case 2:
                      farmZookeeper.push_out_animal(new Animals::Sheep(1,
                      Template::random<unsigned int>(0, 1)));
                      break;
                  case 3:
                      predatorZookeeper.push_out_animal(new Animals::Lion(1,
                      Template::random<unsigned int>(0, 1)));
                      break;
                  case 4:
                      predatorZookeeper.push_out_animal(new Animals::Tiger(1,
                      Template::random<unsigned int>(0, 1)));
                      break;
                  case 5:
                      predatorZookeeper.push_out_animal(new Animals::Puma(1,
                      Template::random<unsigned int>(0, 1)));
                      break;
                }
            }
        }
      }
      animal->sleep();
    }

    // sleep 2 seconds
    // usleep(2000000);
  }
  std::cout << "------- Finish zoo simulation  -------" << std::endl;
  director.last();
  return 0;
}
```

`Animal` constructor and declaration because `Meateater` gets it inherited:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "../template/Animals_vec.h"
#include "Animal.h"
#include "../employees/Zookeeper.h"
#include "../animals/meateater/Meateater.h"
#include "../animals/grasseater/Grasseater.h"

namespace Animals {
  /**
  * @brief   to set gender
  */
  std::unordered_map<int, std::string> mapping = {
     {0, "female"},
     {1, "male"}
  };

// ------ constructors -----
Animal::Animal(unsigned int water_demand, unsigned int food_demand,
  std::string name, unsigned int deadm, unsigned int deadf,
  unsigned int mating_age, unsigned int g_p_animals, unsigned int age,
  unsigned int gender)
  : FOOD_DEMAND(food_demand),
    hungry(true),
    NAME(name),
    AGE(age),
    GENDER(mapping[gender]),
    DEADM(deadm),
    DEADF(deadf),
    MATING_AGE(mating_age),
    WATER_DEMAND(water_demand),
    thirsty(true),
    live(true),
    G_P_ANIMALS(g_p_animals) {
    std::string s;
    if (GENDER == "male") {
      DEAD = deadm;
    } else {
      DEAD = deadf;
    }
    if (AGE < (DEAD/50)) {
      s = "young";
    } else {
      s = "old";
    }
    std::cout << "animal constructed: " << NAME << " : "
    << AGE << " " << s << " " << GENDER << std::endl;
}

// ------ destructor -----
Animal::~Animal() {
  std::string s;
  if (live) {
    if (AGE < (DEAD / 50)) {
        s = "young";
      } else {
        s = "old";
      }
  }
  if (live != true) {
    s = "DEAD";
    }
    std::cout << "animal destructed: "<< NAME << " : "
    << AGE << " " << s << std::endl;
}

// ------ member functions -----
void Animal::drink(Consumables::Water* water) {
  assert(water != nullptr);
  if (AGE < (DEAD / 50)) {
    if (thirsty) {
      thirsty = !water->consume(0.25*WATER_DEMAND);
    }
    if (thirsty) {
      std::cout << "animal drinking failed: " << NAME <<  std::endl;
    } else {
      std::cout << "animal drinking: " << NAME << " : "
      << 0.25*WATER_DEMAND << " L" << std::endl;
    }
  } else {
    if (thirsty) {
      thirsty = !water->consume(WATER_DEMAND);
    }
    if (thirsty) {
      std::cout << "animal drinking failed: " << NAME <<  std::endl;
    } else {
      std::cout << "animal drinking: " << NAME
      << " : " << WATER_DEMAND << " L" << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
void Animal::sleep() {
  if (AGE >= DEAD) {
    live = false;
  } else {
    AGE++;
    if (GENDER == "female") {
      l_pregnancy++;
      if (l_pregnancy > G_P_ANIMALS) {
        PREGNANCY = false;
      }
    }
  hungry  = true;
  thirsty = true;
  std::cout << "animal sleeping: " << NAME << " " << AGE << std::endl;
  }
}

bool Animal::get_mating() {
  if (AGE >= MATING_AGE && PREGNANCY == false) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
bool Animal::get_animal_live() {
  if (live == true) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
void Animal::pregnancy() {
    PREGNANCY = true;
    l_pregnancy = 0;
}
std::string Animal::get_gender() {
  return GENDER;
}
unsigned int Animal::get_age() {
  return AGE;
}
std::string Animal::get_name() {
  return NAME;
}

}  // namespace Animals
```

`Lion`/`Tiger` definition and constructor declaration, the two constructors look the same up to the name:

definition:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include "../../consumables/Water.h"
#include "../../consumables/Meat.h"
#include "Meateater.h"

namespace Animals {
/**
* @brief implements a lion
*/
class Lion : public Meateater{
  /**
  * the amount of water the lion drinks if she is thirsty
  */
  static const unsigned int WATER_DEMAND_LION = 5;  //  drink 5 liters
  /**
  * the amount of food the lion eats if she is hungry
  */
  static const unsigned int FOOD_DEMAND_LION  = 4;  //  eat 4 kilograms

 public:
  /**
  * @brief adjusted the constructor
  */
  Lion(unsigned int age, int gender);
};

}  // namespace Animals
```

declaration:

```cpp
namespace Animals {

// ------ constructors -----
Lion::Lion(unsigned int age, int gender)
  : Meateater(WATER_DEMAND_LION, FOOD_DEMAND_LION, "lion",
    Template::random(10, 12), Template::random(14, 16),
    Template::random(2, 3), Template::random(2, 5), age, gender) {
}

}  // namespace Animals
```

`Liger` definition:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include "../../../consumables/Water.h"
#include "../../../consumables/Meat.h"
#include "../Meateater.h"
#include "../Lion.h"
#include "../Tiger.h"

namespace Animals {
/**
* @brief implements a liger
*/
class Liger : public Lion, public Tiger , virtual public Meateater {
  /**
  * the amount of water the lion drinks if she is thirsty
  */
  static const unsigned int WATER_DEMAND_LIGER = 5;  //  drink 5 liters
  /**
  * the amount of food the lion eats if she is hungry
  */
  static const unsigned int FOOD_DEMAND_LIGER  = 5;  //  eat 5 kilograms

 public:
  /**
  * @brief adjusted the constructor
  */
  explicit Liger(unsigned int age, int gender);
};

}  // namespace Animals
```

`Liger` declaration:

```cpp
 #pragma once

 #include <iostream>
 #include <cassert>
 #include "Liger.h"
 #include "../../../template/Random.h"

namespace Animals {

 // ------ constructors -----
 Liger::Liger(unsigned int age, int gender)
      : Meateater(WATER_DEMAND_LIGER, FOOD_DEMAND_LIGER, "liger",
        Template::random(10, 12), Template::random(14, 16),
        Template::random(2, 3), Template::random(2, 5), age, gender),
        Lion(age, gender), Tiger(age, gender) {
}
 }  // namespace Animals
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a good idea to show the definition of `Liger` when the error shows that `Meateater` is not a direct base of `Liger`? Anyway, the error is pretty clear. You can only initialize the `Lion` and `Tiger` basees.

Comment: Also since Lion and Tiger inherit from Meateater, to you refer to Meateater base of Lion or Meateater base of Tiger? Check out the diamond problem in class inheritance.

Comment: ALX23z you have right it is the dimond problem. I've read up a bit but haven't found a solution yet. But thank you in advance. I'll keep looking to see if I can find a solution. I hope someone will be so kind as to explain the temanics to me

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'main class'? Is it 'base class'? If so, please use standard terminology.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use [Virtual Inheritance](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance) to form what you need (you didn't show that you used it):

```
class Lion : public virtual Meateater  {}
class Tiger  : public virtual Meateater  {}
```

With this your code shown above should compile. The Liger class should initialize Meateater directly, since otherwise it is ambiguity which way (Lion or Tiger) to initialize it.

Others classes should use multiple inheritance. Every base class should initialize only its part, based on information provided by the derived class. Reshape this way and issues will self-resolve.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think there is a misunderstanding. I would like to apologize for that. How i try to explain is that Animals have not only meateater it also has grasseater. grasseater have as subclasses sheep, cow and pig. Therefore have i thought that it will be better do write the constructor only once for all animals. That's why lion and tiger get their constructor from meateater and this inevitably from animals. That's why the constructor is adjusted on them both. And yes you have right i didn't show the use of the code. I will edit the post soon as possible.

Comment: @Blue_Eye, then your picture and class hierarchy is wrong. You could use multiple inheritance (from the same link I posted in my answer) and derive both meateater and grasseater from animal. Now common constructor code will be in the animal constructor. The meateater and grasseater willl keep their specific code.

Comment: you have right. It was entirely my fault. i have correct the mistakes

Comment: @Blue_Eye, the answer has been updated, take your chance to use before I remove it, since now it marked as not useful and if not balanced, I will remove it.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. I have only one question, then you can remove it. I now understand how 'liger' should look like. But there the question arises how it would look like with a subclass of Meateater and Grasseater. Because if you use the same principle as 'liger' you would have a problem with the class definition of the Meateater and Grasseater class at the latest. Because if you don't set the to class Meateater : public virtual Animal { you cant define the new subclass but when you do it then would have to change all the subclasses of Meateater and grasseater or?

Comment: @Blue_Eye, the answer's usefulness has been balanced to zero, so I will keep it for readers' benefit. BTW, you may mark it as accepted if you like. On your question, if you still have issues, I would recommend to put the small piece of code that make trouble for you on https://godbolt.org (easy, free, doesn't require registration) and post a new specific question with a link to the code. I believe, preparing it you will see the answer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much i have fixed it.
The fix are i must set `lion` and `tiger` from:

```cpp
class Tiger : public Meateater {
```

to

```cpp
class Tiger : public virtual Meateater {
```

and fix my `liger` definiation from:

```cpp
class Liger : public Lion, public Tiger {
```

to:

```cpp
class Liger : public Lion, public Tiger , virtual public Meateater {
```

and the declaration from:

```cpp
Liger::Liger(unsigned int age, int gender)
      : Lion(age, gender), Tiger(age, gender), Meateater(WATER_DEMAND_LIGER, FOOD_DEMAND_LIGER, "liger",
        Template::random(10, 12), Template::random(14, 16),
        Template::random(2, 3), Template::random(2, 5), age, gender) {
```

to:

```cpp
Liger::Liger(unsigned int age, int gender)
      : Meateater(WATER_DEMAND_LIGER, FOOD_DEMAND_LIGER, "liger",
        Template::random(10, 12), Template::random(14, 16),
        Template::random(2, 3), Template::random(2, 5), age, gender),
        Lion(age, gender), Tiger(age, gender) {
}
```

how Damir explaind:
"The Liger class should initialize Meateater directly, since otherwise it is ambiguity which way (Lion or Tiger) to initialize it" and this was my problem. My `liger` dont initialized it directly.

At first it look like this:

```
             Animals
           /         \
  Meateater           Grasseater
  /    |    \        /     |     \
Lion  Tiger  Puma   Cow   Pig   Sheep
  \    |  
    Liger
```

but the solution is this:

```
             Animals
           /          \
    Meateater           Grasseater
  /   |   |    \        /     |     \
Lion  |  Tiger Puma   Cow   Pig   Sheep
  \   |  /  
    Liger
```

Comment: Answers should explain things mostly in words, rather than relying on the reader to interpret the code. Also, there's a lot of irrelevant code in this answer, increasing confusion.

Comment: Sorry. I changed it. But I'm not very good at explaining. I have explained it as best as I can